# RESTlet Authorization Filter

Tags: java, restlet

I am developing a RESTlet API (JAVA), and I've created a custom authorization filter that I run all requests through before passing it to my router.  In my requests I always pass the session ID as a request attribute, e.g.

```
    http://localhost:8080/myAPI/{sid}/someResource/
```

Now, in my functions that extends *ServerResource*, I can do something like this to easily extract that *{sid}*:

```
    String sid = (getRequestAttributes().containsKey("sid")) ? getRequestAttributes().get("sid").toString() : "";
```

My problem is, in my authorization function, which extends *Filter* (the authorization function is not called via a router, but is called in my main *createInboundRoot()* function), I cannot use the same method to extract the *{sid}*.  I've created a workaround using string manipulation of *request.getResourceRef().getSegments()*, but there must be a better way?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a common *parent class* for any child of `ServerResource`. like this:

```
public class CommonParentResource extends ServerResource
{
    // class definition
}
```

And then *override* the `doInit()` method of the ServerResource class in it.

```
public class CommonParentResource extends ServerResource
{
    public void doInit()
    {
        boolean authorized=false;

        String sid = getRequestAttributes().containsKey("sid") ? (String)getRequestAttributes().get("sid") : StringUtils.EMPTY;

        // Authorization logic here.

        if(!authorized)//after authorization process completed.
        {
            getResponse().setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED);
            getResponse().setEntity(/*Representation carrrying message for unauthorized user*/);
        }
    }
}
```

Now any new child class of `ServerResource` that you want to perform this authorization check, must extend this `CommonParentResource` class. Like this:

```
public class FriendsListResource extends CommonParentResource
{
    @Get
    //......
}
```

Two points are important here:

1. `doInit()` of any child class of `ServerResource` is called before calling any method annotated with `@Get` / `@Post` / ...
2. (Caution) If you do not use this statement:

   ```
   getResponse().setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED);
   ```

   i.e. if you do not set *status* of *response* to an *error*, then methods annotated with `@Get` / `@Post` / `@Put` / ... will get called ! But if your program sets the status of the response to an error-status, then the `@Get` / `@Post` / `@Put` / ... will not get executed, and the end user will see the error message represented by:

   ```
   getResponse().setEntity(/*Representation carrrying message for unauthorized user*/);
   ```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek! That is quite a nice answer.  I'm giving this a shot.